# Adobe Air Database

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I have 3 Questions

1) Can Adobe Air Database create more than 1 table in the DB?
 will it work by just executing two create table statement work?

```
sqls.sqlConnection = sqlc;
sqls.text = "Create table if not exists test_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);"
sqls.execute();
sqls.text = "Create table if not exists test_table2 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);";
sqls.execute();
```

2) How can i do SQL indexing for a table in a database?

```
sqls.text= "create index index_1 ON test_table (first_name);";
sqls.execute();
```

Will this work for indexing?

3) If all the above work, how to i check if the database is implementing the above?

Comment: Your post is much easier to read if you TURN OFF CAPSLOCK when you're typing. All CAPS in SQL is fine, if that's how you prefer to type it. In the title and text of your question, though, it makes it more difficult to read. Also, it's considered SHOUTING, and yelling at us won't get you help faster. :)

Comment: will this be better? no intention of shouting, codes was copy and paste from somewhere.therefore it was in caps.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes.

2) Yes.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html  I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can force the use of an index in SQLite via the `INDEXED BY` keyword: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html

Comment: so indexed BY is used in every select query i make to enforce indexing on that select statement?


anyway to check if index is created in the database schema?

Comment: @user1004413: If a SELECT uses INDEXED BY, it will use that index to help perform the SELECT.  So yes, I suppose it would incidentally prove that the specified index actually existed...

Comment: that means i will have the create the index in the table before i could used indexed by in my select statement?

I thought by indexing the table, all the select queries will be implementing with the index